# JSON Parse Specific Input String

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, graph

Facebook api is presenting me with an array in the format of:

```
to[0]=10100811338393761,to[1]=10100919262065481,...
```

Any thoughts on how to parse that into a JSON array with JS?

**Edit**: Clarity has been requested, so...

Facebook provides an array of users who have been sent requests in the callback URL ([see here for docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0#response)). It provides that in a URI format, in this case:

```
to%5B0%5D=10100811338393761....
```

I've cleaned that up using decodeURIComponent, and the code I presented is what I'm left with.

What I'd like to do is parse that into a JSON object so I can access the IDs, but when I try JSON.parse, it throws errors ("unexpected [" or "unexpected =").

Comment: what do you mean JSON Array? It looks like an array already?

Comment: I doubt the API literally returns this response. Could you provide a better example? If you are just asking how to parse JSON, that has been asked already.

Comment: I've responded with an edit to be more clear...

Comment: I still think you are doing something wrong. If you were supposed to process the data in any way, it would have been made available to you in a simpler format.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't seem right, but it's what the docs suggest and it's the query string provided. I can't think of how else to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it actually returns **EXACTLY** the way you said:

```
function toObj(a){
    var split = a.split(/to\[[0-9]{1,}\]=(.*?),*?/g));
    var arr = [];
    if(!split) return arr;
    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
      if(split[i] != '') arr.push(split[i].replace(/,/g, ''));     
    return arr;
}


toObj('to[0]=10100811338393761,to[1]=10100919262065481')[0]
                === '10100811338393761'; // true
```

**UPDATE**: Fixed a bug with regex issue. Formatting as well.

Comment: @user3688196 Awesome! This is quick and dirty solution. I would suggest you improve my regex expression and try to remove that `if(split[i] != '')` and `.replace(/,/g, ''))` and basically just return the `split` variable directly!

Comment: Thanks again, was going to figure that out for myself. Much appreciated for going the extra mile to provide the exact correct solution